# Can I use gitlab API with project hosted on gitlab.com?

Tags: gitlab

This question seems simple, but I cannot find any answer on official site.

I have also tried out gitlab API with plenty url variations (an ofc. with real credentials):

```
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com', email='foo@example.com', password='asdf')
gl.auth()
```

But it always fails with:

> gitlab.exceptions.GitlabAuthenticationError: 404: {"error":"404 Not
>   Found"}

I want to add some feature to my kicad/git workflow and I need make some stuff automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab have decided to remove the `/session` endpoint that the python gitlab module uses for password authentication.

You will need to look into the cookie or access token authentication methods instead.

Read [this github issue thread](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/issues/380) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the API for SaaS Gitlab.com is active.

Use this link to retrieve the first batch of projects: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects

I am not aware of the libary which you are using here, but you can try to replace `https://gitlab.com`with `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/`

Further it is not a good practice to insert passwords into the source code. For that reason there are tokens. That way you can limit the access to specific tasks and prevent anybody, who gets in possession of the code, to takeover your account. 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#authentication

Comment: "Further it is not a good practice to insert passwords into the source code" Yes, I know. It's just example. ;) There would be message box prompting for credentials.